# Renombrar/Guardar imagen pasada desde Ajax a C#

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net

Tengo el siguiente codigo el cual muestra una imagen en un thumbnail usando jQuery, la cual mi idea es pasar "La imagen" de ajax al controlador para hacer lo que necesito

```
$('#subirFoto').on("change", function (event) {
    $("#arrastreImagen").html("");
    var salida = $("#subirFoto").val();
    alert($("#subirFoto")[0].files[0]);
    salida = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
    $("#arrastreImagen").append('<span><i class="fa fa-times btn btn-danger eliminarFoto"></i></span><div id="imagenBeer"><img src="' + salida + '" class="img-thumbnail"></div>')
    $.ajax({
        url: "guardarImagen",
        method: "POST",
        data: { img: salida },
        async: false,
        //dataType: "json",
        success: function (respuesta3) {


        }
    });
});
```

Se como capturar el dato en el controlador pero como hago para recibir la imagen (no se si el dato que estoy pasando sea el correcto), renombrarla y guardarla en "X" carpeta del proyecto? Gracias

Comment: hay buena cantidad de preguntas similares... https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=ajax+imagen revisa y en caso no encuentres información relacionada, vamos viendo cómo solucionamos tu caso :D Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entiendo que lo que necesitas es recibir un multipart

```
                var provider = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(new InMemoryMultipartFormDataStreamProvider());

                // aca obtenes los datos del formulario
                document = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DocumentVersionDTO>(provider.FormData["formData"]);
                // aca obtenes los files
                foreach (var file in provider.Files)
                {
                    // esto devuelve un byte[] con eso podes hacer lo que quieras, ponerlo en la base de datos o crear un file en un disco.
                    var archivo = file.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
                }
```